# Installing and running .apk in Android Virtual Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

He, I have downloaded Android Development Tool (ADT) and have setuped it.

I have also created a virtual emulator. Now I have to run/test/install downloaded .apk file in the emulator but dont know how to do it.

Please, suggest me a way to do this.

The package directory map is as:

> HOME >> Developer >> adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729....

These path further contain two folder:

> 1. sdk
> 2. tools

Now i need yours help how and where to install and run the .apk file in the emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, install the adb and fastboot in the repositories with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Then navigate to the directory where the .apk is at using cd and the terminal window.
Start the emulator, and get the emulated device running.
Use:

```
adb devices
```

to check that the device is being recognized. (make sure it says emulator, and that you don't have a phone plugged in)
After that, use:

```
adb install NameOfYourFile.apk
```

That will install it into the emulator.

source: used this process 10 mins ago and worked flawlessly. (http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/install-adb-and-fastboot-android-tools.html)